# Передать/хранить тип Enum

Tags: java, android, kotlin, generics, enum

Возможно не данный вопрос будет не совсем правильным, но задача обстоит следующего характера:

Есть приложение, в котором много перечисляемых значений, по типу:

```
Gender:
MALE(R.string.female),
FAMALE(R.string.male)

HowMany:
EVERY_DAY(R.string.every_day),
ONCE_WEEK(R.string.once_week),
THREE_A_WEEK(R.string.three_a_week),
ONCE_MONTH(R.string.once_month),
ONCE_YEAR(R.string.once_year),
ETC(R.string.etc)
```

И так далее, они разных типов, некоторые возможно в будущем будут содержать не только строки. Они будут приходить из сервака, и храниться в БД.

По дизайну есть достаточно специфичная вьюшка, на подобие `spinner`, который пришлось кастомизировать из нескольких инных вьюх. Так же использую `DataBinding` и при помощи биндинга передаю enum во вьюшку, но хотелось бы как-то унифицировать вьюшку, так как таких вьюшек будет также много как и перечисляемых значений.

**Вопрос:** Как использовать в этой вьюшке унификацию принимаемых значений?

Сейчас список наполняю так:

```
for (item in Gender.values()) {
  popupMenu.menu.add(item.resId!!)
}
```

Вместо `Gender` нужна переменная, которая принимала бы любые Enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Ответ дан с использованием java)*

> нужна переменная, которая принимала бы любые Enum

**Ответ:**

Для того, чтобы передать параметром метода любой `Enum` следует использовать  обобщение. Припустим, у нас есть метод, принимающий любой подтип `Enum` и перебирает его константные значения:

```
public <E extends Enum<E>> void foo(E e){
       for(Enum<E> item : e.getClass().getEnumConstants()){
            // do something
       }
    }
```

Заметьте, что в этом примере не используется метод `values()`. Все потому, что он не есть методом `Enum`. Компилятор автоматически добавляет этот метод для всех подкласов `enum`. Следовательно, если мы используем как параметр дженерик, то этого не будет достаточно для того, чтобы вызвать `values()`.

**Но**

Конкретно в вашем примере это не получится. В цикле вы вызываете специфичное для `Gender` поле `resId`. Любой `Enum` не подойдет.

**Решение:**

Для начала нужно создать интерфейс, который будут реализовывать все `Enum`, что содержат ID ресурса. Пример:

```
public interface ResourceContainer {
    int getResourceId();
}
```

Теперь, нужно имплементировать наш интерфейс во всех enum-классах, содержащих ресурс:

```
public enum Gender implements ResourceContainer {
    MALE(R.string.male){
        @Override
        public int getResourceId() {
            return this.idResource;
        }
    },
    FEMALE(R.string.female){
        @Override
        public int getResourceId() {
            return this.idResource;
        }
    };
    protected int idResource;
    Gender(int idResource) {
        this.idResource = idResource;
    }
}
```

Теперь модифицируем метод  описаный выше под нашы нужды. Доставать Id ресурса будем через наш новый метод `getResourceID()`:

```
      public static <E extends Enum<E> & ResourceContainer> void updatePopupMenu(Class<E> resourceContainer,
                                                                               PopupMenu popupMenu){
        for (ResourceContainer enumValue : resourceContainer.getEnumConstants()) {
            popup.getMenu().add(enumValue.getResourceId());
        }
    }
```

Так, как мы не можем инициализировать `enum`, параметром метода следует передать класс. Вызов метода будет выглядеть так:

```
  updatePopupMenu(Gender.class, popupMenu);
```

Как-то так.

Comment: Спасибо, хорошая реализация, но не совсем понимаю как это можно использовать в кастомной вьюшке. Ведь я передаю тип через @BinderAdapter (статичный метод) и энумчик нужно сохранить в поле вьюшки, но каким это поле должно быть, не понятно.

Comment: @Valeriy не знаком с дата биндингом, но если нужно сохранить enum в поле, используйте `Class`. Например: `Class idContainer = Gender.class;`.